# How to compare if multidimensional elements of an array are present in another array with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, comparison

I'm looking mainly for a numpy-like solution, but any other efficient solution is welcome.

I want to detect if the pixels' colors of an image are present or not in another array that stores a set of RGB colors. I  have the pixels' colors stacked in the `rgb_img` array of `(1, n, 3)`, and I have a `set_color` array matrix `(1, n, 3)`.

```
color_set = np.array([[[ 75,  99, 147],
                       [ 75,  98, 148],
                       [ 75,  97, 154],
                       [ 75,  97, 156],
                       [ 75,  97, 157]]], dtype=np.uint8)

rgb_img = np.array([[[ 2,  3,  4],
                     [ 9, 11, 15],
                     [11, 14, 19],
                     [75,  97, 155],
                     [75,  97, 156],
                     [ 5,  6,  9]]], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Desired result:

```
[False, False, False, False, True, False]
```

Comment: `(color_set == rgb_img[:, :, None]).all(-1).any(1)`?

Comment: Hi @user3483203, that seems great, I'm seeing if it works in the real scenario that I'm working. Also, I noticed that I made a mistake in my desired result, It missed one `False`.  I want it to have the 'length' of `rgb_img`.

Comment: Just to let you know, I tested it, it worked like a charm!